# Error retrieving data from MySQL using PHP from remote server

Tags: php, mysql, d3.js

I am trying to do some visualization using D3.js and I am fetching data from MySQL data, converting it to JSON using PHP script. I am logging to server and accessing the DB from there and hence using PHPSECLIB for remote connection. I am able to successfully get the result of $myquery but when I am accessing each row and saving it in an array I am facing an error :

`Login to MySQL Success /usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/blog/ElitePass/login.php:22: Fatal Error: 'fetch_row' is an unknown method of binary(187) "f02dn7    5.92 f02dn8 11.16 f02dn1    11.31 f02dn6    11.34 f02wn03   2.09 f02dn5 13.41 f02dn4    5.69 f02wn01    2.09 f02dn2 10.81 f02wn08   2 f02wn07   2.09 f02wn09    2.34 f02wn04    1.94 f02wn05    2 f02dn3    11.34 ".`

Is there any issue with the fetch? any help or inputs are highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//open connection to mysql db

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');

include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('194.66.8.10);
    if (!$ssh->login('root', 'passcode')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
    }
    if (!$ssh->exec('mysql -h localhost -u root -pserverdata \r\n')){
    exit('Login to MySQL Failed');
    }else{
   echo "Login to MySQL Success";
}

$myquery = $ssh->exec("mysql -N -h localhost -u root -phadoopcode serverdata -e \"SELECT servername,memory_used FROM test_metrics_summary;\"");

//create an array

$emparray = array();

 while( $row = $myquery->fetch_row())
{   
    echo $row;
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
?>
```

Comment: uh, what makes you think that whatever text that the mysql command line interface spits could **EVER** be used as an object in php? You haven't connected to mysql. you've connected to an SSH server and are executing the mysql command line interface remotely. As written, this code is utterly impossible to ever get working.  php knows NOTHING of mysql's comnand line interface, therefore php's mysql functions cannot EVER be used to use/parse any output from that ssh connection.

Comment: @MarcB what is the best way to execute MySQL commands remotely with this SSH command? Kindly let me know.

Comment: don't. just... don't. either use ssh to establish a port forwarding, so your php code can connect "locally", which ssh transparently forwards on to the remote server, or just connect directly to the mysql server (if necessary, firewall the ip/port so only your mysql client machine can connect) etc...

Comment: If you really really need to do it like so use the SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'whatever_file_path'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' and download/parse the csv file after. But as Marc B already pointed out, there are better ways.